# Extending ant classpath in build.xml

Tags: ant

Is it possible to add libraries (normally specified with `-lib` switch) to ant's classpath from inside build.xml ?

Taskdef supports dynamic loading of task libraries but what I want to load is not a task but rather a compiler adapter for `<javac>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at the [bootstrap options](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html#bootstrap) for the javac task.

Comment: That's a property (option) of sun javac compiler which ant simply passes through.

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki Sorry I don't really understand then what you're trying to do :-(

Comment: Well, I want to set `-lib` from inside build.xml (or rather do something equivalent).

Comment: @MarcinWisnicki Strictly speaking you can't because you're trying to set the bootclasspath. In fact most ant tasks have "classpathref" attributes that allow to specify the classpath, and selected tasks like "javac" have an additional "bootclasspathref" attribute that enables to perhaps solve your issue.... I don't understand the specifics of what you're trying to do, so hopefully this helps.